# "postLink" method in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Ok, let's say I have simple HTML

```
<foo name="outter-1">

  <foo name="inner-1-1"></foo>
  <foo name="inner-1-2"></foo>

</foo>
<foo name="outter-2">

  <foo name="inner-2-1"></foo>
  <foo name="inner-2-2"></foo>

</foo>
```

And directive `foo`

```
import {Directive, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'foo'
})
export class FooDirective implements OnInit{
    @Input()
    public name:string;

    constructor () {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('OPEN', this.name);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('CLOSE', this.name);
    }
}
```

Which should "traverse" my components template, and inform me about structure. What I get is:

```
OPEN outter-1
OPEN inner-1-1
OPEN inner-1-2
OPEN outter-2
OPEN inner-2-1
OPEN inner-2-2
CLOSE inner-2-2
CLOSE inner-2-1
CLOSE outter-2
CLOSE inner-1-2
CLOSE inner-1-1
CLOSE outter-1
```

Which is not true, I need to get result like:

```
OPEN outter-1
OPEN inner-1-1
CLOSE inner-1-1
OPEN inner-1-2
CLOSE inner-1-2
CLOSE outter-1
OPEN outter-2
OPEN inner-2-1
CLOSE inner-2-1
OPEN inner-2-2
CLOSE inner-2-2
CLOSE outter-2
```

`ngOnInit` does its job but `ngAfterViewInit` not.

In angular 1.x I would use `preLink` and `postLink`, but here I'm not sure if it is even possible to get what I need.

I have tried all "Lifecycle Hooks" (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) but some of them seems to be working only with components..

Here is a Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QqScXKAo755ae8Vtfy03?p=preview